# Как сделать откат на копии sql месяц назад на определенное время?

Tags: sql, sql-server

есть 2 базы одна находиться на "sql 2005", другая на "sql 2012" ежедневно делается бекап ночной, и ежедневно одна копия перетирает другую, Модели востановления везде стоят "Полные", почитал что при полной модели можно откатиться на определенную дату и время, но при моей попытке указать свою дату в 2005 sql он либо откатывает в самое начало базы в 2017 год, либо с последнего снятия бекапа ночного, так же и с 2012 , выбираю контрольную точку месяц назад, хочу загрузить и пишет ошибку что отсутствует копия на опред число (см. скрин), вот я не пойму как это правильно должно работать, нужно хранить кучу бак файлов ежедневных по 9гб, и при откате на месяц на определенное число у меня должна быть копия выгрузки на то число, или я где то не правильно что то настроил, и достаточно иметь один бак файл с помощью него откатиться куда надо при правильной настройке.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если я правильно помню, полный бэкап позволяет откатиться только на дату этого бэкапа. Хотите откатываться на разные даты - не затирайте бэкапы за эти даты. Хотите сэкономить место - делайте полный бэкап на какую-то дату, а затем какое-то время инкрементальные бэкапы, тогда вы сможете восстановиться на дату полного бэкапа либо на любую из дат последующих инкрементальных бэкапов. Вроде так это всегда работало. Полный бэкап экономит время, инкрементальный экономит место. Нет бэкапа на дату - вы не сможете откатиться на эту дату.

Comment: спасибо начал читать про инкрементальные бекапы и вроде разобрался как все делается)